# Mac Terminal displays some characters incorrectly

Tags: mac, terminal, osx-el-capitan

My terminal is not displaying characters correctly.  For example, this usage text for the `nc` utility:

[image]

I have found help pages regarding typed characters showing up wrong, but in my case they are displayed wrong regardless of their source.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is a problem with your locale.  If an application (or shell) uses UTF-8, while your Terminal preferences does not, it will occasionally show some of the multibyte UTF-8 as two characters.  Often one of the two looks plausible while the other is C or A with umlauts, etc.

- For the Terminal preferences, check the *Advanced* tab, the **Text encoding** selection.
- for locale settings in the shell, use the `locale` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, both my shell and terminal are set to UTF-8.